# XPlane offsets the yoke in flight, but not in calibration

Tags: x-plane-11

I have a Logitech/Saitek Flight Yoke System (yoke + throttle). Recently, I've been having a problem with the yoke slightly turned to the left. I've checked `joy.cpl`, I've recalibrated it in XPlane, I've reinstalled and uninstalled drivers, but everything looks fine. In other games, it works just fine. As I said, XPlane even says that it's in the same position that it is in real life. But when I hop in a plane, it's always offset to the left, and it really affects the experience. Please help me with this problem.

Some pictures:
XPlane Calibration 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2almJ.jpg

The yoke in the Zibo 787-700U 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQivo.jpg

Comment: Which version of XPlane? I assume 11?

Comment: Yes, the latest version.